# Teradata Volatile table performance

Tags: sql, teradata

I have an issue with creating volatile tables that suddenly appeared overnight.  The source of the volatile table is a query that runs independently in .4 milliseconds and produces 74 records.  When I wrap that query in a volatile table statement WITH DATA and UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX it took 10 minutes.  I am wondering what would cause this.  It appears the query is optimized, it's a small table with 9 columns and I am isolating 4 along with the primary key.  I am not the DBA so this is more of a curiosity question as I will not be able to address the issue. (Unless there is something I can do as an end user...)

Here is the exact query with the column names changed to protect the innocent:

```
CREATE VOLATILE MULTISET TABLE TABLE_NAME_HERE AS
    (
    SELECT PRIMARY_KEY
        ,COLUMN1
        ,COLUMN12
        ,COLUMN123
        ,COLUMN1234
    FROM DB.SOURCE_TABLE
    )
WITH DATA
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( PRIMARY_KEY )
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Comment: The typical reason for slow CREATE TABLE AS SELECT is a SET table with a bad PI, which is not the case here. Maybe workload management moves your query in a throttled workload (your DBA will know)

Answer (score 2):

The issue was related to the delay time.  CREATE/INSERT statements were inadvertantly de-prioritized by the DBAs.  This issue was corrected 3 days later and everything went back to normal.